# How to acess/export holoviews (HexTiles) rendered data

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

Is there a way to access the aggregated data contained in, e.g.,

```
import holoviews as hv
import numpy as np
hv.HexTiles(np.random.rand(100,2)).options(gridsize=4)
```

that is the locations and values (here: counts) of all hexagons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, matplotlib performs the aggregation internally but the bokeh backend uses an operation that returns the aggregated data, and `q` and `r` coordinates, which define the hex grid. You can import and use the operation like this:

```
import holoviews as hv
import numpy as np
from holoviews.plotting.bokeh.hex_tiles import hex_binning


hextiles = hv.HexTiles(np.random.rand(100,2))
df = hex_binning(hextiles, gridsize=4).dframe()
df.head()
```

If you need to compute the hexagon's x/y-locations you'll have to read up on hexagon [offset coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254655/hexagon-grid-coordinate-system).

Comment: Awesome! Just the values is fine actually, I'm looking to scatter HexTiles against each other.

Comment: And if anybody comes here looking for the `geoviews` side of things, `from geoviews.plotting.bokeh import geo_hex_binning` accepts a `projection=` kwarg just like the corresponding plot option.